# Dictionary not adding values properly

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
public Dictionary<string, BuySellPrices> tauntPrices = new Dictionary<string, BuySellPrices>();

public struct BuySellPrices
    {
        public int buyPrice;
        public int sellPrice;
    }

private void TextTauntPriceUpdate()
    {
        var lines = System.IO.File.ReadLines("tauntprices.txt");
        foreach(var line in lines)
        {
            string[] parts = line.Split('.');
            tauntPrices.Clear();
            tauntPrices.Add(parts[0], new BuySellPrices {buyPrice = Convert.ToInt32(parts[1]), sellPrice = Convert.ToInt32(parts[2])});
        }
    }
```

tauntprices.txt looks like this:

https://pastebin.com/m0LY1Qw5

Then again I have this code

```
                TextTauntPriceUpdate();
                foreach(var each in tauntPrices)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(each.Key);
                    Console.WriteLine(each.Value.buyPrice.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine(each.Value.sellPrice.ToString());
                }
```

The problem is that `writeline` only prints out the last line of the text file.

http://prntscr.com/7neq7t

Another problem is if I don't try to print out via the dictionary but do it like this:

```
                var lines = System.IO.File.ReadLines("tauntprices.txt");
                foreach (var line in lines)
                {
                    int bp = 0, sp = 0;
                    string[] parts = line.Split('.');
                    int.TryParse(parts[1], out bp);
                    int.TryParse(parts[2], out sp);
                    Console.WriteLine(parts[0] + ":" + bp.ToString() + ":" + sp.ToString());
                }
```

It works completely fine. What is the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are clearing the contents of the dictionary for each line in the file. That's why it only ends up holding the last line.

```
foreach(var line in lines)
{
    string[] parts = line.Split('.');
    tauntPrices.Clear(); // ****OOPS!
    ...
```

Move the .Clear() line to before the foreach statement:

```
tauntPrices.Clear();
foreach(var line in lines)
{
    string[] parts = line.Split('.');
    ....
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you are clearing the dictionary values each time, with this statement `tauntPrices.Clear();`